# how to approach Spring boot constructor based dependency injection confusion/frustration when unit testing a component class with several dependencies

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to write unit tests for a Spring boot service using JUnit 4 and Mockito.

I used constructor based dependency injection for my service, The Signature is:

```
class VbServiceImp(val jdbcTemplate: NamedParameterJdbcTemplate,
                   val nuanceService: NuanceService,
                   val conf: AppConfigProps,
                   val eventService: EventServiceImp,
                   val audioTrimService: AudioTrimServiceIF,
                   val vbNuanceStagingDeletionsService: VbNuanceStagingDeletionsService) : VbService {...}
```

in another part of the application This service gets injected into a controller and somehow spring just magically knows what to inject without me specifying this (Any idea how this works/explanation would be appreciated, guess it's based on component scan?)

example:

```
class VbController(val vbService: VbService) {...}
```

Now in my VBServiceImpl Unit test class I try to mock all the above dependencies before declaring vBService in order to manually inject all dependencies into VBService during declaration.

the relevant part of my test class looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@ContextConfiguration()
class  VBServiceTests {
    @MockBean
      val jdbcTemplate: NamedParameterJdbcTemplate = mock()

    @MockBean
     val nuanceService: NuanceService = mock()

    @MockBean
    val appconfigProps: AppConfigProps = AppConfigProps()

    @MockBean
    val eventService: EventServiceImp = mock()

    @MockBean
    val audioTrimService: AudioTrimService = mock()

    @MockBean
    val vbNuanceStagingDeletionsService: VbNuanceStagingDeletionsService = mock()


    val vbService: VbServiceImp = VbServiceImp(jdbcTemplate,   nuanceService, appconfigProps, eventService, audioTrimService, vbNuanceStagingDeletionsService)

    @SpyBean
    val vbServiceSpy: VbServiceImp = Mockito.spy(vbService)

@Before
fun setup() {
    initMocks(this)
}
```

When I run a test I get the exception below.  If I understand this correctly there is already a bean of type jdbcTemplate in the application context and therefore I can't define the @Mockbean jdbcTemplate above?

exception:

`private final org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` com.cc.ff.vb.service.VBServiceTests.jdbcTemplate cannot have an existing value

So now the issue is: If I removed the @MockBean jdbcTemplate variable then I can't inject jdbcTemplate when I declare vbService in my test class.  So how could I get around this/make this work?

Just to check I removed the jdbcTemplate parameter from the vbService class constructor and changed it to a @Autowired field injected class variable and provided the mock class using @TestConfig.  This worked however then the exception popped up on the next constructor parameter (NuanceService)

i'm out of ideas and google hasn't returned anything of value.  Do I remove all constructor injected dependencies and then make them field injected using @Autowired and then provide the beans in the nested @TestConfig annotated class or is there a better/cleaner way?  AFAIK field based injection is supposed to be bad practice?

example of providing correct bean for testing @Autowired field injected jdbcTemplate variable:

```
@TestConfiguration
    class testConfig {
        @Bean
        fun jdbcTemplate(): NamedParameterJdbcTemplate {
            return mock<NamedParameterJdbcTemplate>()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up making it work:

```
@TestConfiguration
    class testConfig {
        @Bean
        fun jdbcTemplate(): NamedParameterJdbcTemplate {
            return mock<NamedParameterJdbcTemplate>()
        }

        @Bean
        fun nuanceService(): NuanceService {
            return mock<NuanceService>()
        }

        @Bean
        fun appConfigProps(): AppConfigProps {
            return mock<AppConfigProps>()
        }

        @Bean
        fun eventService(): EventServiceImp {
            return mock<EventServiceImp>()
        }

        @Bean
        fun audioTrimService(): AudioTrimService {
            return mock<AudioTrimService>()
        }

        @Bean
        fun vbNuanceStagingDeletionService(): VbNuanceStagingDeletionsService {
            return mock<VbNuanceStagingDeletionsService>()
        }
    }
    
    @MockBean
    lateinit var nuanceService: NuanceService

    @SpyBean
    lateinit var vbServiceSpy: VbServiceImp
```

I'm still not sure if this is the best/optimal way of going about this so would appreciate some more details...